# Cant get proper element from XML when parsing

Tags: objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

my XML page look like this:

```
<announcement>
  <body>
```

... then many tags follow

```
<files>
  <images originalSize="101554" id="4641530">
    <description>Ласковый покалеченный приютский пёс Федя в дар.</description>
    <image id="21126492" url="http://dmir.ru/images/laskovyy-pokalechennyy-priyutskiy-pes-fedya-v-dar-21126492.jpg" name="first" width="56" height="56"/>
    <image id="21126493" url="http://dmir.ru/images/laskovyy-pokalechennyy-priyutskiy-pes-fedya-v-dar-21126493.jpg" name="prev" width="103" height="77"/>
    <image id="21126494" url="http://dmir.ru/images/laskovyy-pokalechennyy-priyutskiy-pes-fedya-v-dar-21126494.jpg" name="prev_card" width="158" height="124"/>
    <image id="21126495" url="http://dmir.ru/images/laskovyy-pokalechennyy-priyutskiy-pes-fedya-v-dar-21126495.jpg" name="middle" width="462" height="348"/>
    <image id="21126496" url="http://dmir.ru/images/laskovyy-pokalechennyy-priyutskiy-pes-fedya-v-dar-21126496.jpg" name="default" width="640" height="482"/>
  </images>
  <images originalSize="146409" id="4641531">
    <description>Ласковый покалеченный приютский пёс Федя в дар.</description>
    <image id="21126497" url="http://dmir.ru/images/laskovyy-pokalechennyy-priyutskiy-pes-fedya-v-dar-21126497.jpg" name="first" width="56" height="56"/>
    <image id="21126498" url="http://dmir.ru/images/laskovyy-pokalechennyy-priyutskiy-pes-fedya-v-dar-21126498.jpg" name="prev" width="103" height="77"/>
    <image id="21126499" url="http://dmir.ru/images/laskovyy-pokalechennyy-priyutskiy-pes-fedya-v-dar-21126499.jpg" name="prev_card" width="158" height="124"/>
    <image id="21126500" url="http://dmir.ru/images/laskovyy-pokalechennyy-priyutskiy-pes-fedya-v-dar-21126500.jpg" name="middle" width="284" height="348"/>
    <image id="21126501" url="http://dmir.ru/images/laskovyy-pokalechennyy-priyutskiy-pes-fedya-v-dar-21126501.jpg" name="default" width="554" height="680"/>
  </images>
```

...other 3 tags with image, then closing tag `<body>`

There is about 40 similar XML elements with image, text tags and rest, i don't want to put it all here because its quite large.

My point is, i can easy parse each element like that:

if `([elementName isEqualToString:@"text"])`, then save it to an array, but, there is a lot image tags. When i can easy find corresponding text or description tag, i can't find proper image, because there is a lot of them. I want to get an image with proper width/height (one from 30), and then save it and move further, but now the best i did is have array of unsorted image links like this:

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"]){

        self.imageString = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
        if (self.imageString) {
//        NSLog(@"%@", self.imageString);
        }

       [self.listOfImages addObject:self.imageString];
```

Ohh, i really hope you here with me and now u get my point and what i want to do. How can i get proper image string (one from many) that correspond to proper key (when i tried to use keys i found that solution not working, because each element contain 5 keys, for example i want single element with key "url", which further have key "prev", and also want only one object with that parameters).

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Edited:  i tried to compare two strings like this, maybe that would help to figure out correct string:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"images"]){

        descriptionNew = [self.currentPosition objectForKey:@"description"];

        }


    if (descriptionOld == descriptionNew){
        NSLog(@"equal");
    }   else {
        newElement = YES;
        NSLog(@"not equal");
    }
```

Then BOOL newElement could be used to remove last object from an array.. but  i think that approach not very good, solution should be simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> when i tried to use keys i found that solution not working, because each element contain 5 keys, for example i want single element with key "url", which further have key "prev", and also want only one object with that parameters

You could accomplish that with something like:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"])
{
    NSString *name = attributDict[@"name"];

    if ([name isEqualToString:@"prev"] && self.imageURLString == nil) 
    {   
        NSString *urlString = attributeDict[@"url"];
        if (urlString)
        {
            self.imageURLString = urlString;
        }
    }
}
```

Elsewhere, though, you said:

> When i can easy find corresponding text or description tag, i can't find proper image, because there is a lot of them. I want to get an image with proper width/height (one from 30), and then save it and move further ...

You'd have to describe what rules you want to apply to determine the "proper width/height". You could probably just want to have the parser save each of the `image` the whole `attributeDict`:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"])
{
    [self.listOfImages addObject:attributeDict];
}
```

You could then, when you're done parsing all of the `images`, iterate through all of these and identify which is "best" and prune the rest away if you want. You could also do this as you're parsing (e.g. save the `attributeDict` of the "best image thus far", and every time you parse a new one, see if the dimensions are better, and if so, replace the "best image" with the current one).

But without knowing the precise rules you want to apply, it's hard to be more specific than that.

Comment: Solution u give me is correct, but how can i create that image string only once per body tag, not several times? I careless about image i will have as long as it correspond to same body tag

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban And how to do you want to choose the image amongst all of the available images?

Comment: I want to have only single image for each corresponding body or files tag, I'm not sure how to solve this, somehow i need to remove all unwanted elements from image array to have only one for each main tag like body or files

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Yes, I know you only want one. So, capture all of the images in `listOfImages` (like my final example), and then when you get to `didEndElement` for `images` element name, iterate through `listOfImages` and choose the one that best matches whatever criteria you want to apply. Tell us by what criteria you want to pick the image, and we can tell you how to pick one. If you don't tell us precisely what the criteria is, we can't tell you how to do it.

Comment: You already chose correct criteria - "prev " key, now i got images like this : http://dmir.ru/images/moshcnyy-umnyy-krasivyy-pes-ramzes-broshen-v-priyute-20589042.jpg, next is the same, but last number is slightly different, for example it will be http://dmir.ru/images/moshcnyy-umnyy-krasivyy-pes-ramzes-broshen-v-priyute-20589044.jpg. What i need it remove other string with same text (and different number) from an array. Sorry those links not appear in way i want to, my point was last characters was different numbers, like 20589042 and 20589043, in array that was different objects ..

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Ok, and how do you want to pick from those occurrences with the `prev` key? Use the first one encountered? Use the last one? What is your criteria for picking one?

Comment: Doesn't matter Rob, anything that  would fit from those who match "prev ". Last or first, any of those would be  perfect

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Ok, let's assume you have some `NSString` class property, `imageURLString`, you can then test to see if it's `nil`, and if so, set `imageURLString` accordingly. See first code sample in revised answer. Just make sure to set `imageURLString` to `nil` when you start the next `body`/`files` tag.

Comment: you might be glad to hear that everything went pretty fine, and i actually spend whole 11 hours yesterday trying to fix this problem, i really appreciate your help a lot, that was rather simple solution for such problem as mine, thank you!